# R - add title to images with rasterImage

Tags: r, raster, r-grid

I have 12 twelve PNG files which I want to combine in a single plot with 4x3 grid in R.

So far I can create the grid with,

```
plot(c(0,4), c(0,3), type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

and I can add images to it with,

```
rasterImage(readPNG("image1.png"), 0, 3, 1, 2)
rasterImage(readPNG("image2.png"), 1, 3, 2, 2)
```

etc.

I get what I want, but I also want to add a title to each image in the plot. Like image1 should have **a. Image1** and image2 should have **b. Image2** on top of the images. Is there a way to do in R?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BondedDust's suggestion to use `text` is perfect, but using the `mfrow` (or `mfcol`) graphic parameter in `par` to layout the grid of plots might be sensible. You can then use `plot(..., main='foo')` or `title(main='foo')` to add the titles. For example:

1. Download some example png graphics, and read them into a list:

   ```
   library(png)
   pngs <- lapply(LETTERS[1:12], function(x) {
     u <- 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mattahan/umicons/64'
     download.file(mode='wb', sprintf('%s/Letter-%s-icon.png', u, x), 
                   f <- tempfile(fileext='.png'))
     readPNG(f)
   })
   ```
2. Use `mfrow` to set the plot to have 4 rows and 3 columns, and add an upper margin for titles with `mar`. Then use `sapply` (for example) to iterate over elements of `pngs` (well, actually the indexes, `1` through `12`, of the elements), plotting each in turn:

   ```
   par(mfrow=c(4, 3), mar=c(0, 0, 3, 0))
   sapply(seq_along(pngs), function(i) {
     plot.new()
     plot.window(xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), asp=1)
     rasterImage(pngs[[i]], 0, 0, 1, 1)
     title(paste0(letters[i], '. Image ', i), font.main=2)
   })
   ```

[image]

Comment: Better than mine. I was going to suggest `main=bquote(bold(.(paste(LETTERS[i], '. Image', i))))` but then I noticed you had used the font=2 option.

Comment: @BondedDust I'm yet to familiarise myself with `bquote`, `expression`, `plotmath`, etc. It does my head in for some reason!

Comment: I've seen your other contributions on SO. I have no doubt that with a bit of time that they will become useful tools for you. I happen to think the ?plotmath page is very poorly written. I paid attention to worked examples by Peter Dalgaard and Gabor Grothendeick on Rhelp to learn it.

Comment: @BondedDust - thanks for the tip. I'll devote some time to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 text(x=0.5,y=2.95, labels="a. Image1")
 text(x=1.5,y=2.95, labels="b. Image1")
```

If it needed to be bold, then plotmath expressions are needed:

```
text(x=1.5,y=2.95, labels=expression( bold(b.~Image1) )  )
```